# How to remove top and bottom margin/padding from angular material mat-row/mat-cell

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular material mat-table with the standard row height and I would like to reduce that height to fit only the text. No space above and below the text.

I tried it directly in the mat-cell like this but no success:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="abc" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length" style="margin-top:0; margin-bottom: 0; padding-top:0; padding-bottom: 0;">
```

In browser dev tools this is what I see:

```
<mat-row _ngcontent-qcx-c52="" role="row" class="mat-mdc-row mdc-data-table__row cdk-row ng-star-inserted"><mat-cell _ngcontent-qcx-c52="" class="mat-mdc-cell mdc-data-table__cell cdk-cell cdk-column-abc mat-column-abc ng-star-inserted" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;" role="cell" colspan="15"> Title text </mat-cell><!--ng-container--></mat-row>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add ng-deep

```
::nge-deep {
 .mat-row, .mat-cell {
      line-height: 1; /* Adjust this value as needed */
      padding: 0 !important;
    }

    .mat-table {
      border-spacing: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: ng-deep is deprecated. Anyways I tried, but it still didn't remove top and bottom space.

Comment: ::ng-deep is deprecated for some time, but there is no alternative approach for now, as far as I know. With ::ng-deep you should be able to style every aspect of material design elements. In your case just find right classes/tags that you should tweak.

Comment: ng-deep is deprecated.

Comment: what angular material version are you using? if > V15, you might need to run "ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration" to migrate all your components. mat-* became mat-mdc-*.